# Kivy (Python) - Ellipse Click Event

Tags: python, oop, canvas, kivy

I'm trying to translate the beginnings of [a simple canvas app](https://bloom510.github.io/pitch-canvas/) I wrote in JavaScript to the Kivy framework. I have been able to distribute vertices along the perimeter of a circle, but I have been unsuccessful in registering click events on each vertex whether attempted in Python or Kv language. A nice start might be changing the size of any vertex clicked. Any tips, feedback, solutions welcome.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from random import randint
import math

class Vertex(Widget):
    def __init__(self, position=(50,50), **kwargs):
        super(Vertex, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.position = position
        self.size = (10,10)


    def draw(self):
     with self.canvas:
        Color(1., 0, 0)
        Ellipse(pos=self.position, size=self.size)


class ChromaticCircle(Widget):
    vertices = []

    def __init__(self, radius=100, **kwargs):
        super(ChromaticCircle, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = radius
        self.draw()

    def draw(self):
        interval = (math.pi * 2) / 12

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1., 0, 0)

            for i in range(1, 13):
                angle = (math.radians(360) / 12) * (i + 9)
                position = ((self.center_x + 200) + (self.radius*math.cos(angle)), (self.center_y + 200)+(self.radius)*math.sin(angle))
                self.vertices.append(Vertex(position))

            for j in range(len(self.vertices)):
                self.vertices[j].draw()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChromaticCircle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can capture clicks on your `Vertex` widget by using the `collide_point` method in the `on_touch_down` method to check if a `Touch` event occurs within a `Vertex`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from random import randint
import math

class Vertex(Widget):
    def __init__(self, position=(50,50), **kwargs):
        super(Vertex, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.position = position
        self.size = (10,10)
        self.pos = position    # need to set the `pos` as `collide_point` uses it

    def draw(self):
     with self.canvas:
        Color(1., 0, 0)
        Ellipse(pos=self.position, size=self.size)


class ChromaticCircle(Widget):
    vertices = []

    def __init__(self, radius=100, **kwargs):
        super(ChromaticCircle, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.radius = radius
        self.draw()

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        # check if the touch is on a Vertex
        for vert in self.vertices:
            if vert.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
                print('click on vertex: ' + str(vert.pos))
                return True
        return super(ChromaticCircle, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def draw(self):
        interval = (math.pi * 2) / 12

        with self.canvas:
            Color(1., 0, 0)

            for i in range(1, 13):
                angle = (math.radians(360) / 12) * (i + 9)
                position = ((self.center_x + 200) + (self.radius*math.cos(angle)), (self.center_y + 200)+(self.radius)*math.sin(angle))
                print('adding vertex at ' + str(position))
                self.vertices.append(Vertex(position))

            for j in range(len(self.vertices)):
                self.vertices[j].draw()


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ChromaticCircle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

There are some additional details that you may want to consider. The `pos` of the `Ellipse` is the lower left corner, so your vertex position is not at the center of the drawn `Ellipse`.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughtful response. This helps my understanding of Kivy, though I'll be moving forward in React.

Comment: I on the other hand am just starting Kivy, and this post is very useful!

Comment: @ShineOnYouCrazyDiamond this is off topic, but you have a nice username ^_^

Comment: @bloom.510 thanks :).  "Come on you painter, you piper, you prisoner, and shine!"