# Ellipse Position

Tags: kivy, kivy-language

Re: [Kivy (Python) - Ellipse Click Event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53715810/kivy-python-ellipse-click-event)

In the linked thread, the vertices drawn are not positioned relative to the center of the ellipse.

This code is similar to my own, albeit a simplified version. I have tried to adjust the position calculations but have been unsuccessful.

Using the existing code, how can I ensure the vertices are positioned relative to the ellipse?

Note: I wasn't sure whether it was best to start a new thread, reference the existing one, or just paste the relevant code in here, so apologies if I have made the wrong choice.

Comment: provide your version of the code with your request instead of providing StackOverflow link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the linked question, the `Ellipse` can be centered on the vertex `position` using this `draw` method:

```
   def draw(self):
        self.pos = (self.position[0] - self.size[0]/2.0, self.position[1] - self.size[1]/2.0)
        self.canvas.clear()
        with self.canvas:
            Color(1., 0, 0)
            Ellipse(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```